# why Ubuntu Firewall not showing verbose?

Tags: command-line, firewall, ufw

Even Ubuntu Firewall in running mode, I am not getting the data. may I know why ?

```
# sudo ufw status numbered
Status: inactive

# service ufw start
start: Job is already running: ufw

# sudo ufw status numbered
Status: inactive

# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enable the firewall using

```
sudo ufw enable
```

After you enable, `sudo ufw status verbose` should show you the following:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip
```

To check more options use, `ufw help`

For more on ufw logging, see this answer:

- [UFW logging](https://askubuntu.com/a/113619/72576)