# UFW not logging on fresh 20.04 install

Tags: ufw, logging

I am not getting any UFW logs in `/var/log/ufw.log`.
I have tried everything on

- [UFW is not logging how do I troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113439/ufw-is-not-logging-how-do-i-troubleshoot)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2380393.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/516838/where-are-the-logs-for-ufw-located-on-ubuntu-server/1075984#1075984

to no avail. `sudo dmesg | grep UFW` does show me UFW logs, so they are ending up somewhere...

This is a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install, just a stock OS install with a UFW installed via apt-get. Since I do see logs when grepping dmesg, but they are not going to any log I can find...

How do I find the log that's actually written to?

Answer (score 0):

Logging is generally not enabled with `ufw` by default because the files can get very big, very quickly. That said, if you would like to enable the logs, you can do so like this:

```
sudo ufw logging on
```

From here, you'll see `ufw.log` file in `/var/log` that rotates with the same schedule as the rest of the files in that directory.

One thing to note is that the logging level is set to `low` by default. Depending on how verbose you would like the logs to be, you can change the setting like this:

```
sudo ufw logging medium
```

The different levels [as outlined in the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ufw.8.html#logging):

| Option | Verbosity |
| --- | --- |
| `off` | disables `ufw` managed logging |
| `low` | logs all blocked packets not matching the defined policy (with rate limiting), as well as packets matching logged rules |
| `medium` | log level `low`, plus all allowed packets not matching the defined policy, all INVALID packets, and all new connections. All logging is done with rate limiting. |
| `high` | log level `medium` (without rate limiting), plus all packets with rate limiting |
| `full` | log level `high` without rate limiting |

Note that if you do want to keep all of the UFW logs on a heavily-trafficked web server (500+ requests per minute), you will want to ensure `/var/log` is on a flash-based storage device and *ideally* has about 20GB of free space with a log shipping plan in place to move rotated logs off the machine.

Comment: Logging is on but I still get no logs written. Thanks for the tip on growth, I dont plan on persisting them, I just want to have fail2ban watch them to block port scanning.
# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip